# Spring boot cannot find beans

Tags: spring-boot

i have a Spring Boot project which has some external packages i need to import as Beans in the main application.

So i have my main application in com.package.app package and some classes (among which some repositories) in com.package.commons package.

In order to take these beans i have my main class annotated as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.package.commons" ,"com.package.app"})
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class EmanagerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{


     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(EmanagerApplication.class, args);
        }

}
```

But when i launch the application it may occur (not always but very ofter) that the start up fails with these kind of error:

```
Description:

Field repository in com.package.commons.service.BrandService required a bean of type 'com.package.commons.persistence.repository.BrandRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.package.commons.persistence.repository.BrandRepository' in your configuration.
```

My BrandRepository is annotated with `@Repository` and the service class with `@Service`

The really strange thing is that if i keep launching the app at the end it stars... but there is no reason for it...

Comment: Strange strange... What happens if you remove `@ComponentScan` and place your main class in `com.package`?

Comment: I have the same structure as you with my repositories and services in a separate project (since 2 projects use them) and I recall randomly getting this kind of error also.  Never been able to explain it but I just compile it again and it works.

Comment: @akuma8 same behavior... my main class is already in com.package

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JPA, you'll also need the [@EnableJpaRepositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) annotation.

Also consider to use [@EnableTransactionManagement](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) to enable declarative transaction handling.

E.g. use something like the following in the same package or a parent package where you have your JPA entities and JPA repositories (untested):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.AbstractJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

    public HibernateConfig(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties, ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager,
            ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManager, transactionManagerCustomizers);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }
    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        return new HashMap<>();

    }
}
```

And don't forget to annotate your @Service classes also with @Transactional.

Answer (score 0):

If you confirm that the `Application` which with the startup method of this application is good, and confirm the `@ComponentScan` is good also. And the configuration file `yaml` or `properties` of JPA also good.

How about trying extends JPA Repository like this:

```
public class xxxResponsitory extends JpaRepository<T, E>{
    ...
}
```

Cause `JpaRepository` has already annotated with `@Repository` annotation, `T` means the type of `Primary Key`, I always use `Integer` or `Long`, autoboxing type. `E` means the main type of this repository.
Make an example:
Now we have an Entity type named `User`, the Primary key type of `User` is `Long`, I would write the repository like this:

```
public class UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, User>{
   ...
}
```

Don't need annotated anything, then, In the service class, `@Autowried` `UserRepository`, everything is good to run. But make sure the things that I talk at the start of my answer.

Hope this can help you.